# Is there alter way to clean cache without drop_caches?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I'm running ORACLE db instance and recently oracle is shutdown and can't bring up.
I'm not sure , but it seems that Oracle can't be bring up because of memory issue.

Below is my system memory status.

```
[root vm]# free
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6234244    5762280     471964          0     104732    5497360
-/+ buffers/cache:     160188    6074056
Swap:      2096472        128    2096344
```

If you see the above about 5G memory is cached.
Most article suggest to use "/prov/sys/vm/drop_caches", but my system doesn't have it.
( /prov/sys/vm folder is exist , but drop_caches isn't there )
Is there any way to clean the cache without drop_caches ?

I use RHEL4.

```
[root vm]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

mem used for caching should be auto reclaimed if needed
I.E. you should need to mess with that?

Comment: I believe that cache has to be reclaimed.
In my case, Oracle was down abnormally, so I guess some memory has garbage data.